# Getting variable to pass to multiple places

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get the groupname variable to pass in two places, what i have, the variable outputs to the first position but not the second

```
    gc .\ddgroups.txt |% {write-host 
data `"okta_group`" `"$_`" {
>>   name = "$_"
>>   type = "APP_GROUP"
>> }}
```

The output is this, the second $_ does not get the groupname var, it just passes the $_

```
data "okta_group" "groupname"
  name = "$_"
  type = "APP_GROUP"
```

Comment: seems like you're trying to pass an argument in the form of a json object. if that was the case then you definitely need to change your approach and use `ConvertTo-Json` instead

Answer (score 2):

The `$_` is rendered verbatim because you've enclosed it in a scriptblock literal `{...}`.

Use a [here-string](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.3#here-strings) instead:

```
Get-Content adgroups.txt |ForEach-Object {
@"
data "okta_group" "$_"
  name = "$_"
  type = "APP_GROUP"
"@
}
```